# Convert Validation from Rails 3 format to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this validation works on Rails 3:

```
validates_length_of :password, :within=> 8..25, :on => :create
```

which causes error when I try to load my object in rails console on rails 4

I converted it to the following on Rails 4:

```
validates :password, :length=>{:within=>8..25}, :on => :create
```

No I get no error, but I does not validates when I save the object

What does I wrong?

Comment: do you save object by skip validation like `save(validate: false)` or other way

Comment: no, just object_name.save

Comment: please do `object_name.save!` bang sign after `save`

Comment: No difference at all!

Comment: did you able to see this validation methods  after doing  `User.validators` here `User` is you model class name

Comment: #<ActiveMod
el::Validations::LengthValidator:0x3a4e650 @attributes=[:password], @options={:o
n=>:save, :minimum=>8, :maximum=>25}>]

Comment: Could your post your whole User model source code?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
validates :password, length: 8..25, on: :create
```